# @font-face not working without www

Tags: web, font-face

When I load my site with WWW.example.com the custom fonts will load.

But if I just enter domain.com (without www) the fonts wont load in IE or Firefox but will in Chrome.

All my CSS files links are absolute.

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Be careful of XSS restrictions. Since you didnt say I'm assuming your links go to `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`. Browsers are wary of requesting files from other domains. You can set it to request from `/path/to/css.css` instead of an absolute link.

Comment: Fixed!

In .htaccess file I made it redirect to WWW if NON-WWW url was entered :)

Comment: please mark this answer as accepted if it was the right solution. It helps other people find the answer more readily.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of CORS (which basically means that browsers will not request resources from a server *b*  that did not send the original document (which instead came from a server *a*) specifying the request, UNLESS *b* specifies that it will take requests that originate from *a* resources).

See http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ and http://enable-cors.org/